# htaccess rewrite suffix /lang/en to subdomain 301

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've recently created a subdomain for my english language equivalent on my site and now want to rewrite the old urls to that subdomain.

the old url looks like `http://mydomain.com/filename/lang/en`

I want to redirect ALL the urls that end with `/lang/en` to the subdomain e.g. `http://en.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want http://mydomain.com/filename/lang/en to be redirected to http://en.mydomain.com/filename put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/lang/en$ http://en.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise, if you want http://mydomain.com/filename/lang/en to be redirected to http://en.mydomain.com put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/lang/en$ http://en.mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for these lines!! works great, just wat I want!